# facebook oauth dialog doesn´t start

Tags: facebook, oauth

Hi i got the following problem:
I want the user to authenticate my app, so i want to show the authorisation dialog.
To do this, i tried the api function

```
FB.api("/dialog/oauth", "get", {client_id: APP_ID, redirect_uri: URI}, function(response){
    console.log(response);
});
```

But i get this error:

```
code: 2500
message: "Unknown path components: /oauth"
type: "OAuthException"
```

But why? The FB.api call should be the same like

```
http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=<app-id>&redirect_uri=<uri>
```

If i put this url in the browser directly, the dialog is shown. ('window.location' also doesn´t work because of x-frame-options)

Answer (score 1):

Use JavaScript SDK's **FB.login** method http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/